# Custom Gradle Task cannot be used in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy

I've created custom Gradle task:

```
package org.gradle

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class GenerateSthTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    void generate() {}
}
```

it is located in `src/main/groovy` under the package `org.gradle`

but when I try to use it in build.gradle

```
import org.gradle.GenerateSthTask

plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
}

tasks.register("generate", GenerateSthTask)
```

then gradle is unable to resolve class

I would be glad for any help with that.
Thank you

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:packaging_a_task_class

Comment: there is nothing regarding importing custom task to build.gradle

Comment: "it is located in src/main/groovy" - You probably want it under `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`.